# How do I find all xml elements of a specific type using xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, dom4j

I have an XSD that defines a complexType (say 'FooType'), and several named instances of this type scattered throughout the same XSD, like:

```
<sequence>
    <element name="A" type="tns:FooType"/>
    <element name="B" type="tns:FooType"/>
</sequence>
```

When working with an XML file derived from the XSD, I want to find all element nodes that of the type "tns:FooType". I think this is possible using XPath with the element(*, "FooType) method, but I can't find any examples of this so don't know what the syntax would look like. I'm hoping to use this with the Java dom4j selectNodes() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an XPath 2.0 implementation. DOM4J is 1.0 only, and so is javax.xml.xpath. Saxon provides 2.0, but I believe this specific capability is not part of the open source edition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List list = document.selectNodes( "/sequence/element[@type='tns:FooType']" );
```

Comment: I think what you suggested would select from the XSD. I need something that will select from the XML that is derived from the XSD.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the prefix you could use `substring-before()` on the name and check if there is a result:

```
/sequence/element[substring-before(@type,":FooType")]
```